# Difference between secret of connect.session and connect.cookieParser?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, node.js-connect

I'd like to use secure cookies in my Express application using Connect's modules [`connect.session`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) and [`connect.cookieParser`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html). As per the docs, both accept a `secret` parameter. This key is used to prevent the user from tampering with the cookie.

Should I set the same key to both modules, or two different ones? Or should I only pass a key to one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to set it with one or the other. Though, you can pass to each in order to give them different `secret`s to use.

The difference between them is in their so-to-say "*greediness*" with it.

- `session(secret)` will keep the `secret` to itself, only using it for the cookie holding the session ID.
- `cookieParser(secret)`, on the other hand, will allow for any cookie to be signed.

  You can create signed cookies with Express' [`response.cookie()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie).

  > Signed cookies are also supported through this method. Simply pass the `signed` option. When given `res.cookie()` will use the secret passed to `express.cookieParser(secret)` to sign the value.
  >
  > ```
  > res.cookie('name', 'tobi', { signed: true });
  > ```
  >
  > Later you may access this value through the [req.signedCookies](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.signedCookies) object.

Comment: Great, so if I understand you correctly, they are completely independent of each other? I.e. if I use two different keys, there won't be somekind of key mismatch issue?

Comment: @Tom Well, `session()` will use the `secret` passed to `cookieParser()` if it isn't given its own. But, otherwise, yeah. They shouldn't conflict with each having their own `secret`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Does this imply that using two separate keys is more secure as to using the same key for both the parser and the session middleware?